# Nesting Swipeviews

Tags: javascript, html, carousel, mobile-website, swipeview

I've come across a situation where I have parent SwipeView carousel (works fine) and inside one of the pages I need to make an image carousel (with swiping). I was hoping to use SwipeView for it, but I'm not having much luck. When I swipe the image it begins swiping the parent page as well, thus both pages end up changing.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Stan

```
EDIT: Here's a quick and dirty fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RNTDN/
```

Comment: Could you share some kind of results? Some code or a fiddle would be pretty helpful.

Comment: I did a quick and dirty way but this shows the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/RNTDN/